# How to directly open Office attachments in "Try the New Outlook"?

Tags: office365, file-association, microsoft-excel-365, microsoft-outlook-365, microsoft-word-365

When trying the new Outlook for desktop, each Office attachment has 3 options (with a little triangle):

1. Preview
2. Open in Word/Excel
3. Download

If I choose option 2 it just pops up a message to purchase a "premium" Microsoft 365 subscription. Why doesn't it recognize the existing one and just use it? If I answer yes and sign in the browser window that opens up, it still pops up the same message.

Until this is answered, the only way to to open Office attachments is to choose option 3, then double click them...(meaning file associations are correct).

The only source I found online about it [is unreplied on Microsoft's forum](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook/new-outlook-word-attachments/m-p/3901006). And before you suggest to revert back to the non-new Outlook keep in mind the old one misses crucial features like syncing contacts and calendar on its own. As for the program's settings, it barely has any settings.

[image: New Outlook]

Comment: What version of Office do you have exactly? What is the file extension of the file? If you do have Office why are you using the non-Office Outlook instead of the one included with Office?

Comment: The version was tagged. Files are Word and Excel files. What is a non-Office Outlook and why do you think it's such?

Comment: Office 365 does not tell me which build you are running. Microsoft recently replaced Mail with a version of Outlook, that isn't installed through Office, I think it's called Outlook for Desktop or something like that.

Comment: How to know? There's no Help=>About.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Outlook is too new and still lacks many features that were
in the old Outlook, and the feature you're missing seems to be
one of those.

The feature request
[Open attachments from email in their file format](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/5dbef1b2-05fb-ed11-a81c-000d3a7a48db)
dates from 4 months ago and is still being voted upon by the users.
Up to now it has not been acted upon.

You may also vote for this feature request, then wait for it to be
implemented (if ever).

You could also move to a third-party email client. Perhaps the free
Thunderbird would be a suitable replacement.

That's just about all you can do.

Comment: You'd think opening attachments would be quite basic. This feature request is different than mine. It just asks to change the default click. All I asked was to be able to open attachment, even not by default.

Comment: The feature request is another aspect of your problem - the inability to open attachments by the assigned software application, with another method for doing so. I agree that this is a basic feature and I assume that it will be added sometime in the future, but for the moment the new Outlook is incomplete.